# How can an app enable "Allow Automatic Updating" in the Android market

Tags: android, google-play, auto-update

I noticed that some apps like Google Maps, Facebook for Android etc. (all preloaded BTW), have their "Allow Automatic Updates" check box checked without me doing so.

Is it possible for preloaded apps only?

How can I achieve that with my app?

Comment: Are you sure they are universally?  It could be part of the build for your network specifically, I don't think mine are set to auto update.

Comment: Well, I saw it in numerous operators and devices. Didn't test it universally.

Answer (score 1):

The user has to explicitly check this option. I don't think there is any API to do this from the app.

You could, after asking the user if he wants to (say, in a dialog box), take him to your app's market page, so that he can check it.

Comment: But the question remains, how come some preloaded apps are already checked without me explicitly doing so?

Comment: bcz those are pre-loaded apps. When they make the rom they must have enabled that option for selected aps.

Answer (score 1):

I found this post from google groups that may help you:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e5e77d5d8f05f8d5?pli=1

It explains how this feature works. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Users can opt to allow an app to be auto-updated by the Market.
However, if the permissions for the app have changed, it does not work. The user must manually update and agree to the new permissions. After that, it will continue to auto-update.

That's pretty much it.