# I have published an app on Android Market. How do I allow/enable automated updates for it?

Tags: android, publish, auto-update

In other words - when I search for other apps on android market, I usually see an option for enabling "auto-update" for that specific app. However, when I look at my own app, I don't see such option - why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can an app enable "Allow Automatic Updating" in the Android market](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879785/how-can-an-app-enable-allow-automatic-updating-in-the-android-market)

Answer (score 2):

Given details provided in a [linked conversation](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e5e77d5d8f05f8d5?pli=1) from [Dimitris's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7790428/298053) the fact that you can't check it off is probably due to permissions changes. You'll either need to re-download the app or do a manual update and accept the new permissions.

From what I gather on the searches I've performed, there's nothing in the app itself that defines whether it's update-able (word?) it's just a feature the market offers to version check (and update) for you.